# Group acting on its subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, p-groups

Let $ G $ be a group with $ |G|=mp^\alpha $ where $ \alpha\geq1 $ and p is prime integer with $p \nmid m$. Then denote the set of subsets of G, having $p^\alpha$ size, with $X$.
Then with the action $g \cdot S=\lbrace gs \mid s \in S\rbrace$ for $S \in X$
show that the stabilizer $G_S$ is a p-subgroup of $G$.

Any ideas for how to approach to this question will be appreciated.

Comment: it is general fact that stabilizers are subgroups of the acting group. You ought to check that $g\cdot S$ is indeed an action.

Comment: It is, since pre-multiplication is bijective in subgroups, so the image of a $p^\alpha$-set is a $p^\alpha$ set. It also clearly holds that $g_1*g_2(S)=g_1(g_2S)$ and $eS=S$

Comment: One way to do it is to prove all orbits have size multiple of $m$ But I don't know if this is easier

Comment: I am trying to use the fact that if $g\in G_S$, also knowing the behaviour of this action I deduced that there should be less than $p^a-1$ elements in the stabilizer.

Answer (score 3):

I was going at it all wrong, the idea is to prove all of the elements of the stabilizer have orders which are powers of $p$.

To see this consider an element $g$ of the stabilizer of $S$, it defines a permutation on the set $S$ in which all of the cycles have length equal to the order of $g$. Then the length of the cycles needs to be a divisor of the number of elements in $S$, which is $p^\alpha$. So the order of $g$ is a divisor of $p^\alpha$, hence a prime power.

Since the stabilizer has only elements of order powers of $p$ the stabilizer has prime power order.

Note more generally this strategy works if you are working on subsets of size $k$, where $\gcd(|G|,k)$ is a prime power.

Comment: Nice.  In case it helps anyone (because it took me a second to figure out the rest), one can use the contrapositive of Cauchy's theorem (if there is no element of order $q$ in $G_S$ for a prime $q$, then $q$ can't divide the order of $G_S$) where $q|m$ to finish off the argument.

Comment: @JasonDeVito In the more general setting, one defines a $p$-groups to be one all whose elements have finite order a power of a fixed prime $p$. For example, the Prüfer $p$-group is an infinite $p$-group. By Cauchy, as you note, the equivalence holds for finite groups.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of your set is $$N=\binom{p^\alpha m}{p^\alpha}$$

You should show that $(p,m)=1$ implies $N$ is not divisible by $p$. Now, we know that if $G$ acts on the set $S$ of subsets of size $p^\alpha$, the cardinality of $N$ of $S$ equals the sum of the orbits of this action. That is, $$N=\sum_{i=1}^n | Gx_i|$$ where each $x_i$ is a representative of a unique orbit of the $G$-action. Since $p$ doesn't divide $N$, we know that $p$ doesn't divide *some* of the terms $|Gx_i|$. If $p$ doesn't divide $|Gx_i|$, from $|Gx_i|=|G:{\rm stab}\; x_i|$ it follows that the stabilizer ${\rm stab}\; x_i$ is such that its cardinality $M=p^\alpha n$, $n\mid m$. Can you show that indeed $n=1$?

Note that what you're showing is that *some* stabilizer is a $p$-group.

Comment: why $p$ doesn't divide $N$?

Comment: @janmarqz Have you tried to show it?

Comment: Note that the OP uses $G_S$ for the **stabilizer** and you $Gx_i$ for the **orbits**. In my answer, I followed the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take two $x,y\in G_S$ and then try to find that $xy^{-1}\in G_S$. Completing this scheme assures you that $G_S<G$.

Now, since in one hand we have $$\#X={p^{\alpha}m \choose p^{\alpha}},$$ 
and in another
$$\#X= \sum_{S_i}\#{\rm Orb}(S_i)=\sum_{S_i}[G:G_{S_i}],$$ 
but $p\nmid {p^{\alpha}m \choose p^{\alpha}}$,  then there exists one $S_0\in X$ such that $p\nmid [G:G_{S_0}]$.

This implies that $p$ divides $|G_{S_0}|$. This is because if $p\nmid[G:G_{S_0}]$ then they are coprime, meaning that exists $\lambda,\mu$ integers such that $\lambda p+\mu[G:G_{S_0}]=1$, so $|G_{S_0}|=\lambda p|G_{S_0}|+\mu p^{\alpha}m$ hence the claim.

Similarly also $p^2$ and $p^3$, etcetera, will do divide $|G_{S_0}|$.

Clearly we can proceed just to $p^{\alpha}$ dividing $|G_{S_0}|$.

So $|G_{S_0}|=p^{\alpha}n$ for some $n\in{\Bbb{N}}$.

At this point maybe you can complete de proof. I still can't. As soon I discover, I'll tell you.

Comment: I think the point of the question is not that $G_S$ is a subgroup, but rather, that $G_S$ is a **p**-subgroup.

Comment: ok, and why is the order of $G_S$ a power of $p$?

Comment: ok ok, i'm thinking

Comment: Why would you copy my answer into yours...?

Comment: No Pedro... Why?

Comment: I am asking you. I gave an argument three hours ago. Two hours ago you commented on it, and half an hour ago copied the argument in your answer. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1095970/revisions) you can see the edit history.

Comment: I don't copy you. You should re-check your version, mine is different.

Comment: The argumnent is identical, and the formulas appear in the same order. In fact, your post concludes with the same question as mine.

Comment: The argument _is_ identical. You have a few additional remarks about the divisibility of the order of $G_{S_0}$ by $p^\alpha$, but the timeline being what it is, it looks suspicious. I suggest you edit it to be different.

Comment: No Daniel, maybe they look similar but they aren't identical, why should I steal? you can see my training along the ideas for example in http://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/?s=sylow